# Groovy/Gremlin class naming scheme (capital letter required)

Tags: groovy, gremlin

What is the difference between the following Groovy/Gremlin snippets? (both saved as *.groovy files and run with `./gremlin.sh -e [filename].groovy`)

```
class user
{
    String username

    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        user mtm = new user()
        mtm.username = "MuffinTheMan"
        println mtm.username
    }
}
```

and

```
class User
{
    String username

    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        User mtm = new User()
        mtm.username = "MuffinTheMan"
        println mtm.username
    }
}
```

The first gives 3 compilation errors similar to this one:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 7: Apparent variable 'mtm' was found in a static scope but doesn't 
refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from
a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'mtm' but left out brackets in a place not allowed
by the grammar.
@ line 7, column 14.
user mtm = new user()
```

The second compiles and runs just fine and outputs:

```
MuffinTheMan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the only difference is that the class name in the first begins with a lower case letter, while the class name in the second begins with an uppercase letter.  There's a bit of discussion [**here**](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Class-name-uppercase-problem-td372450.html), but it's difficult to find a lot of good info on the issue.  I decided to post this because I was beating my head against the wall (not literally) trying to figure out why my code (class name having its first letter in lowercase) wouldn't compile, and perhaps others may have this issue.

If anyone else has a better link to a more full/clear discussion on the issue, post it!